# Spring @RequestParam Date Formatting

Tags: java, spring, annotations, http-request-parameters

How do you format the incoming `@RequestParam` using annotations?  The form is sending the date in MM/DD/YYYY format and the controller is not picking it up as a valid `Date`.

```
@RequestMapping(params="/updateDate")
public @ResponseBody String updateDate(HttpServletRequest request
        , @RequestParam Integer productId
        , @RequestParam Date dateReceived) {
    // Code here...
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the Spring annotation [DateTimeFormat](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html)

```
@RequestMapping(params="/updateDate")
public @ResponseBody String updateDate(HttpServletRequest request
        , @RequestParam Integer productId
        , @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy") Date dateReceived) {
    // Code here...
}
```